# Is it possible to bring up a eth0 that's gone down without SSH'ing into it?

Tags: networking, debian

On a Beaglebone Black (running Debian Wheezy), I previously brought up the network by accessing it through USB, and invoking `sudo ifup eth0` without properly configuring `/etc/network/interfaces`. On a separate Beaglebone unit, I've confirmed the absence of an `auto eth0` that would bring up the interface.

Since the network was up and survives reboots and power cycles, I left it alone until recently, when my SSH session suddenly died on me. After rebooting, I was able to SSH into once more for a minute or two and at this point the interface seems to be down for good (ping doesn't work). It has since been rebooted a good two or three dozen times as I tried alternate solutions.

The ttyO0 (serial terminal) and USB ports are permanently inaccessible - all I have is the Ethernet port and a possibly faulty ttO1 port.

Is there any way to get the networking running again so that I can SSH in and reconfigure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Plug an HDMI monitor and a USB keyboard to gain access to the console. Then reconfigure.

Very common problem with Raspberry PI's too.

EDIT: you may need to purchase a small monitor that plugs into it. Raspberries don't have this problem thanks to the onboard hdmi plug.

EDIT2: without USB. Your only option left is to debug the device, make a serial port work over other pins than the dedicated serial port you fried, and recover your data. Sounds to me like a bricked board.

Comment: I did mention that the USB port is inaccessible, unless I cut it out of and scrape (melt?) off the epoxy it's sitting in. The P8/P9 headers are accessible due to a serial cape that's sitting on top of it, but the J1 pins (which include the serial terminal) are not.

Incidentally, what exactly happened with the interface? Was it a DHCP lease expiry?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, edited the answer again. Well, you can always hook up a custom serial port by repurposing some I/O pins (very  common on Arduinos) and use that to recover your board. Is there anything valuable on this board?

Comment: In the end the ethernet magically came back after leaving it powered off for a while, so I quickly SSH'd in and fixed the network configuration and got what I needed out of it. I still don't understand what broke the networking, or how it could recover (some DHCP issue?). Regarding the rest of the answer, I'm not entirely sure how you'd go about debugging the device without getting terminal access to it, but I'd agree it was bricked without that magical recovery.

Comment: Great! Debugging these boards is an absolute pain for the inexperienced programmer (you need the hardware and the dev environment), that's why I was asking how important the data was. Nice job on the recovery.